# Display 10 items at a time in list view and next 10 after some scroll and so on

Tags: android, android-listview

I want to display all the installed applications in my phone in a list view. But, I want to display 10 applications at a time. Now, when the user scrolls, another 10(from remaining applications) should be displayed and so on.

Here is my code

```
    List<PackageInfo> packageList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    
            List<String> appNames = new ArrayList<>();
    
            for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packageList) {
                if ((packageInfo.applicationInfo.flags & android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
                 appNames.add(packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
                }
            }
    
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, appNames);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Any suggestion how can I achieve this functionality?

I have implemented RecyclerView instead of list view and here's the code

```
private int visibleThreshold = 10;
--
--
--


        appNames = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new AppListAdapter(appNames);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
                lastVisibleItem = layoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                if (!loading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    // Load the next batch of applications
                    loadMoreApps();
                    loading = true;
                }
            }
        });

        loadMoreApps();
    }

    private void loadMoreApps() {

        int start = appNames.size();
        int end = start + 10;

        List<PackageInfo> packageList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
        for (int i = start; i < Math.min(end, packageList.size()); i++) {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = packageList.get(i);
            if ((packageInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
                appNames.add(packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString());
            }
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        loading = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `RecyclerView` and Paging library

Comment: @Zain I have implemented RecyclerView as suggested by you and added the code for the same, but not getting desired results

Comment: You registered `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener` to the RecyclerView, and Paging library work differently, you don't even need to register that listener; pls have a look on the documentation or any good tutorial to the paging library